# VBA autofilter clashing with a isVisible function

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I've got this isVisible function:

```
Public Function IsVisible(InRange As Range) As Boolean()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' IsVisible
' This function returns an array of Boolean values indicating whether the
' corresponding cell in InRange is visible.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim R As Range
    Dim Arr() As Boolean
    Dim RNdx As Integer
    Dim CNdx As Integer

    ReDim Arr(1 To InRange.Rows.Count, 1 To InRange.Columns.Count)
    For RNdx = 1 To InRange.Rows.Count
        For CNdx = 1 To InRange.Columns.Count
            Set R = InRange(RNdx, CNdx)
            If R.EntireRow.Hidden = True Or R.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
                Arr(RNdx, CNdx) = False
            Else
                Arr(RNdx, CNdx) = True
            End If
        Next CNdx
    Next RNdx
    IsVisible = Arr
End Function
```

And it works fine just until you apply an autofilter with vba:

```
Worksheets("Datos").Range("datos").AutoFilter Field:=pFindColPos(tag), Criteria1:="1"
```

When I execute this, isVisible(whatever cell autofiltered, visible or not) will raise an error.
Just to be clear, if I apply the autofilter manually, this does not happen.

I've been looking around for some time but i'm not able to fix it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with Application.CalculateFull, now it works. However perhaps this is not the best way to do it, so I'll leave the question open just in case someone knows better.